# How to buffer events with Rx extentions for JS

Tags: reactive-extensions-js

I wan't to get text change events from input but limit them to 3 per second.

Rx support my wish? how can I achieve this ability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have the Observeable, insert a call to throttle(333) before you consume should do the trick. (333= miliseconds which is 1000/3 which gives you 3 chars per second).

a very simple sample:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   var mainCanvas = $("#TextBox1");
   var observable = Rx.Observable.FromHtmlEvent(mainCanvas.context, "keypress");

   var throttle = observable.throttle(333);

   throttle.subscribe(function (next) {
         $('div#test').append(String.fromCharCode( next.charCode)); 
        }
   );
 });
```